# Using jQuery html() method in several clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on [this demo](http://www.bootply.com/tkYK17Alqi). I am trying to find out why the HTML disappears after using the second button.

As long as you only click on btn `#from-content-1` or only on `#from-content-2` every thing is fine but if you click on `#from-content-1` and then on `#from-content-2` and back to the `#from-content-1` again, the content disappears!

Here is the code which I have:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="dest">Here is the Destination</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sr-only">
 <div id="content-1">This Is From Content 1</div>
 <div id="content-2">This Is From Content 2</div>  
</div>

<button class="btn btn-default" id="from-content-1">From Content 1</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="from-content-2">From Content 2</button>
```

and js script is

```
<script>
$("#from-content-1").on("click",function(){
  $("#dest").html($('#content-1'));
});

$("#from-content-2").on("click",function(){
  $("#dest").html($('#content-2'));
});
</script>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You move the nodes! Do that instead:

```
<script>
$("#from-content-1").on("click",function(){
  $("#dest").html($('#content-1').html());
});

$("#from-content-2").on("click",function(){
  $("#dest").html($('#content-2').html());
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Gnucki This working but can you please let me know what exactly was happening on my code when you say that I was removing the nodes?!

Comment: When you set the jquery elements retrieved by the selector `#content-1` directly in the `html` method, you move the corresponding DOM nodes, ie. your `div` of id `content-1` inside the `div` of id `dest`. When you do the same for `content-2`, you remove the `content-1` because it is in `dest`! Then, when you click on the button 1 there is no more `content-1` to set in `dest`.

Comment: yeah but it is still in original place `<div class="sr-only"></div>` isn't it enough?

Comment: No you moved it. If you look at the original source in your browser you will maybe still see it but look at your demo in a browser debugger and you will see it is moving.

Comment: @MonaCoder mind that it's move not remove. A node can only be in one place at a time unless you `.clone()` it.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#dest").html($('#content-1'));` should be `$("#dest").html($('#content-1').html());` and `$("#dest").html($('#content-2'));` should be `$("#dest").html($('#content-2').html());`

```
$("#from-content-1").on("click",function(){
  $("#dest").html($('#content-1').html());
});

$("#from-content-2").on("click",function(){
  $("#dest").html($('#content-2').html());
});
```

Comment: Hi Khawer, thanks but can you please let me know what was differ between `$("#dest").html($('#content-1'));` and `$("#dest").html($('#content-1').html());`? thanks

Comment: `$('#content-1')` is an object so you need to use `.html()` to get the html of it similarly `.val()` in case if it is a form element